# How to add number before a column?

Tags: c#

I want to add number 30 before column mobile. i'm using this code:
How will i do this?

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("select mobile from memberform where active=1 or active=0", con)) // only retrieve the column, you really need
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(reader["mobile"] + ",");
    }

    string result = stringBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd(',',' ');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "add number 30"? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Number 30 its my country code of each mobile

Comment: So you want to prepend the text "30" to the value, e.g. using `stringBuilder.Append("30" + reader["mobile"] + ",")`? (If so, it was not *at all* clear what you meant from your question...)

Comment: Simply call stringBuilder.Append(30); first in the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply concatenate that value like

```
stringBuilder.Append("30" + reader["mobile"] + ",");
```

(OR)

change your SQL query itself like

```
select '30' + mobile as mobile_number
from memberform 
where active in (1 ,0);
```